# Why doesn't rendering a template work when there's a trailing slash in app.route?

Tags: url, flask, routes

I'm working with a Flask application and having some route trouble.

The following function works fine (as in renders the template as expected):

```
@app.route('/page1', methods = ['POST'])
def page1():
    ...
    return render_template('page1.html')
```

However, the nearly identical function

```
@app.route('/page1/', methods = ['POST'])
def page1():
    ...
    return render_template('page1.html')
```

is no longer able to load any of the css resources associated with `page1.html`. The html loads without a hitch, it's the just the other resources that are not findable.

If someone has some insight into why the extra trailing slash is making this happen, that would be  great!

Comment: Please share the template.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default flask behavior, [see werkzeug docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/routing/#rule-format%20%22See%20werkzeug%20docs%22.). To change it, use:

```
@app.route('/page1', strict_slashes=False)
```

or to change it universally, change the app behavior:

```
app = Flask(__name__)    
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

Another way is to wrap `@app.route` with :

```
def route(*a, **kw):
    kw['strict_slashes'] = kw.get('strict_slashes', False)
    return app.route(*a, **kw)
```

and use `@route` as your route decorator, routing with or without slashes (instead of `@app.route`).

The last way is preferred as it only applies to routes you *want* this behavior for, rather than a single route, or all routes.